# How to sort audiobook on iTunes?

Tags: itunes, sorting, audiobook

I have a question that might seem dumb, but I didn't find anything on Google.

How can I do to sort my audiobook tracks on iTunes?

I have books with 4 or 5 CDs and I'd like them to appear as one.

I set the meta correctly, track x on 10 and CD number y on 5.

When I setup 1 CD by album, I have no problem, but if I put them all within the same album, itunes put me all tracks 1 then all tracks 2 regardless of the disc number.

My guess is that it is a bug from iTunes, but still, do someone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all of the Audiobook tracks in your library together
2. Right-click and choose `Get Info`
3. In the `Info` tab, set the Artist to be the author, the album to be the title, and the 2nd Disk Number box to be 5.
4. In the `Options` tab set the Media Kind to be Audiobook, set Remember Position to Yes, and Skip when shuffling to Yes, then click OK.
5. Navigate to the `Books` section of your library in `List` view and find the tracks.
6. For each disk, select that group and `Get Info`, then set each disk number to the proper disk number. Then set the 2nd track number to the number of tracks on that disk and press OK.
7. `Get Info` on each track individually and set the track number to the appropriate track number.

This is the "right way" which will set your metadata appropriately, but if it is too much of a hassle, just set the Media Kind to Audiobook and add them to a playlist and arrange the order manually.

Comment: As I said, I already setup all the metadata, but still, itunes will not conside the disc number and put all the track1 cd 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, then track2 cd 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc...
I didn't think to use a playlist, good idea, but it still wierd that itunes does not handle this kind of thing, no?

Comment: @louis8831 I haven't personally had the issue and I'm a fairly heavy user of audiobooks. Usually I find that I have missed something subtle in the metadata when something similar happens to me.

Answer (score 0):

After having this issue with a 14 CD audiobook, I discovered that MediaMonkey (free version) has a tool to auto number the tracks. Just select all, click TOOLS > SCRIPTS > AUTO INCREMENT TRACK #'s.

For me, it auto incremented over 200 tracks in about a second. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a book with 30 chapters. it displays in audiobooks as chapter 1 then chapter 10, then chapter 11 etc. Chapters 2 - 29 come after chapter 19, chapters 3 & 30 display after 29.
The tracks play in the order displayed.
Force the tracks into numerical order by renaming each track eg chapters 1 to 9 are named as book 1.1 chapter 1, 2 ,3 4 etc. Chapters 10 to 19 are book 1.2 chapter 10 , 11 , 12 etc. chapters 20 to 30 are book 1.3 chapter 20 , 21 etc.
The chapters will then sort back into numerical order and play in the correct order.